# Receiving multicast on linux host with multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, multicast

I have a host running Ubuntu 16.04 connected to one network via the primary wired network interface, and to another network via a USB-to-Ethernet adapter. Using `tcpdump`, I am able to verify incoming multicast packets on both network interfaces.  However, my application does not receive any multicast data from the secondary interface.  If I disconnect the cable to the primary interface, and then restart my application, then I do receive the data from the secondary interface.  It is only with both interfaces connected that the application does not receive from the secondary interface.

Comment: You have iterate over the interfaces issuing a JOIN via each interface in turn in a multi homed host.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the pointer.  This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ip_mreq` stucture is passed as the option value for the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` socket option to join a multicast group.  From the [Multicast programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.4) from the The Linux Documentation Project:

> The first member, `imr_multiaddr`, holds the group address you want to join. Remember that memberships are also associated with interfaces, not just groups. This is the reason you have to provide a value for the second member: `imr_interface`. This way, if you are in a multihomed host, you can join the same group in several interfaces. You can always fill this last member with the wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`) and then the kernel will deal with the task of choosing the interface.

The `IP_MULTICAT_IF` socket option is also relevant on a multihomed host to set the outbound interface for multicast data sent via the socket.  More information on these socket options, the `ip_mreq` structure, and the newer `ip_mreqn` stucture is found [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

For those using Boost on a multihomed host, you will need to use the native handle to join the group on specific interfaces.  As of Boost 1.58 running on Ubuntu 16.04, the socket option abstraction `ip::multiast::join_group()` joins the group on an interface of the kernel's choosing and does not allow the developer to specify an interface.  The socket option abstraction `ip::multicast::outbound_interface()` controls the outbound interface but does not affect which interface the socket receives on.

Here is a code sample to join a group on a specific interface based on the local interface IP address:

```
struct ip_mreq mreq;
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(discovery_ip);
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(local_interface_ip);
if(setsockopt(socket_.native_handle(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq))) {
    ... handle error ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem (Raspberry Pi Zero with USB-to-Ethernet adaptor, fails to respond to mDNS queries).  To work out if your problem is the same, does does your app correctly receive multicast traffic whilst running tcpdump at the same time?  And does running tcpdump with `--no-promiscuous-mode` not see multicast traffic?

If your answer is yes to both, then the workaround I've found is simply `ip link set eth0 promisc on`.  I don't know if it is a hardware bug (I'm using a Kontron DM9601 adaptor, ID 0FE6:9700) or a driver bug, but either way, enabling promiscuous mode seems to fix multicast reception for me.  Alternatively you could try a better USB-to-ethernet adaptor.

Comment: Thank you! I have the same DM9601 adapter and this change has fixed the issue where the pi failed to respond to mDNS lookups.